# Clock Driver - What's wrong with my H-bridge design?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, dc-dc-converter, esp32

I'm trying to design a drive board for a vintage slave clock. These things take an alternating 24 V pulse once a minute to advance the display.
Since the drive board should be powered by 5 V, I wanted to use a DC-DC boost converter in line with an H-bridge to generate the drive signal.

The H-bridge is driven by an ESP32 at 3.3 V.

I ordered/built the board but I'm getting strange behavior when trying to use it:

I uploaded some test code which alternates the DRV_A and DRV_B pins every second, ensuring to power both off in between cycles to prevent shoot-through.

The circuit seems to work for a few seconds after powering it up, although not with the expected current output (should be about 200 mA to drive the coil).

After a few seconds, Q1 seems to overload and burns up.

Can you give me some pointers as to how I need to change my design to make it work the way I expect - or am I completely on the wrong path here? I don't have a lot of experience working with MOSFETs.

Datasheets:

A03401A: https://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401A.pdf

A03400A: https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/1133/AO3400A_ds.pdf

[image: H-Bridge]
[image: Power Supply]
[image: MCU]
[image: Blown Q1]

Comment: Please provide the data sheet for the booster module (not the XL6009 chip but the module). Please also describe the load that is connected to the H-bridge output.

Comment: It's this generic module from AliExpress:
https://components101.com/modules/xl6009-dc-dc-step-down-voltage-regulator-module

Comment: The h-bridge is driven in alternating pulses of about 500ms duration with 200ms interval

Comment: No data sheet usually means no help can be given.

Comment: The load that is connected to the h-bridge output is a 24v solenoid coil that draws about 200mA. From what i can see about the boost module it's more or less the reference design specified in the XL6009 datasheet.

Comment: Slave clocks of this kind are often in a chain with many slaves ... for this reason consider using relays, and then you have a very simple circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Q1 dies because its gate-source voltage goes outside its limits. As you can see from the datasheet, its maximum allowed gate-source voltage is ±12V.

But once you enable it, the gate-source sees -24V *(gate at zero, source at 24V)* which is way beyond its absolute maximum limits.

Same applies to Q2 as well.

Change the circuit to something like following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNigv9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you drive the pre-inverter (e.g. Q5) the gate-source voltage of the bridge's PMOS will be limited to -10V with Zener (you can still use resistive dividers and get rid of the Zener diode but make sure the gate-source never exceed -12V).

And always use individual resistors to drive multiple MOSFETs from the same output. In your circuit, Q5-Q4 pair and Q6-Q3 pair are driven from the same outputs. Put individual gate stopper resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWrfY1.png)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Here's an updated schematic from what i could gather from your answer. Do you have any more notes?
https://i.imgur.com/rrLmxaI.png

Comment: @chdabre looks good. R1 and R3 can be omitted, but it won't harm to keep them anyways.